# Creating a dictionary from list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of lists in the following format:

```
[['a'],['1'],['2'],['3'], ['b'],['4'],['5'],['6']]
```

My desired output is:

```
[['a', '1'], ['a', '2'], ['a','3'],['b', '4'],['b', '5'],['b', '6']]
```

or even better would be:

```
{'a':['1','2','3'], 'b':['4','5','6']}
```

Essentially, the "number values" are never the same size (think that a could include 1 2 and 3, and b could include 4 5 6 7 and 8, etc)

What would be the easiest way of doing this?  Using regex?

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of a list of lists rather than a list of elements? You could start by flattening it to a list of elements (or tweak the code that produces the list of lists so that it produces a simple list instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and check if the element is a digit or not:

```
d = {}
for i in lst:

    if not i[0].isdigit():  # Check if element is a digit. If not, add a key with the current value of i[0]
        d[i[0]] = []
        current = i[0]

    else:
        d[current].append(i[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> d
{'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['4', '5', '6']}
```

This is assuming everything in the list is a string

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!